# Parse LET variable names from another cell contents

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

The LET function is really useful for making formula readable and easy to track, but one thing is bugging me about it that I'm unable to figure out. My situation currently is that I'm trying to construct a bunch of user lists using a lookup, and concatenate these together for an easy comma separated list. I have a formula that does this:

```
=IFERROR(
CONCAT(
LET(
// Helper range variables
usernames, Sheet1!$A$1:$A$267,
names, Sheet1!$B$1:$B$267,
emails, Sheet1!$C$1:$C$267,
boards, Sheet1!$D$1:$D$267,
access, Sheet1!$J$1:$J$267,
keep, Sheet1!$O$1:$O$267,
lastaccess, Sheet1!$P$1:$P$267,
board, L31,
date, DATE(2023, 3, 13),
// The conditional to test against for selection of users
conditional, (boards = board)*(access = "")*(lastaccess <= date)*(keep = "?"),
// The valid user list returned as a transposed array
calc, TRANSPOSE(FILTER(emails, conditional)),
// The returned array is then turned into a comma-separated list for easy copy-pasting
calc&", "),
),
"None")
```

What this formula does is take the full list of all users, filters it based on the conditional and returns a comma-separated list of users. The important part of the calc is this `TRANSPOSE(FILTER(emails, conditional))`, where by changing `emails` to `names` or `usernames` etc, we can return a comma-separated list of whatever part we want.

Now the minor issue is that these are separated by a grouping called board, and there are 17 of these "boards". This means that if we want to get the usernames instead of the emails, I have to change the formula in 17 locations (the way I currently have it set up visually prevents a simple formula drag, so to keep the current visuals I'd need to either change the array to be filtered manually, or copy and paste the formula 16 times).

What I would like to be able to do, is just have a field called something like "Field to show", and it could be a dropdown that lets the user select between the `LET` variable names e.g. `emails`, `names` etc, and that is just filled in in the filter. There is a way to do it indirectly, where I could just do `INDIRECT("Sheet1!$A$1:$A$267")` for example, however I was hoping the user could just select "emails", and the LET formula could parse this and use the LET variable `emails`. Is this something that would be possible?

I apologise for this being long, I just wanted to give all the context possible. I have a way of doing it where the user selects from a dropdown, that dropdown then populates a cell with the range as a string, and then `INDIRECT(range)` is used in the LET formula, but I was basically wanting to find out if we could cut out the middle-man cell and just input the variable directly into the formula. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea could be to have your dropdown or input field stored in `K31` and use something like this:

```
=IFERROR(
CONCAT(
LET(
choice, INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$C$267,,XMATCH(K31,{"usernames","names","emails"})),
boards, Sheet1!$D$1:$D$267,
access, Sheet1!$J$1:$J$267,
keep, Sheet1!$O$1:$O$267,
lastaccess, Sheet1!$P$1:$P$267,
board, L31,
date, DATE(2023, 3, 13),
conditional, (boards = board)*(access = "")*(lastaccess <= date)*(keep = "?"),
ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(choice, conditional)))),
"None")
```

Where I figured you'd only be interested in the first 3 columns as output choices, they're next to eachother and a simple INDEX/MATCH could work.

I also used `ARRAYTOTEXT` for putting the commas in between data and avoiding a trailing comma behind the last data. (`TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(choice, conditional))` could also do the trick there).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, never thought about using an XMATCH and taking advantage of the column order! Also I wasn't aware of ARRAYTOTEXT so I can replace the CONCAT hack wherever I've used it, that's great cheers, exactly what I was after.

Comment: Good to hear it helped

Answer (score 2):

### Parse Filtered Column Valus

- Consider using an Excel (structured) table for your data and things will get easier i.e. the ugly `A2:P267,` would become e.g. `Table1`, `boards` could be equal to e.g. `Table1[Boards]`, ... etc.
- Consider drop-downs in `L31:L33`.

[image]

```
=LET(data,Sheet1!A2:P267,
title,L32,
last_date,L33,
board,L31,
boards,CHOOSECOLS(data,COLUMN(D1)),
access,CHOOSECOLS(data,COLUMN(J1)),
keep,CHOOSECOLS(data,COLUMN(O1)),
lastaccess,CHOOSECOLS(data,COLUMN(P1)),
delimiter,", ",
if_not_found,"None",
titles,{"user";"name";"email"},
cols,{1;2;3},
return,CHOOSECOLS(data,CHOOSEROWS(cols,XMATCH(title,titles))),
conditional,(boards=board)*(access="")*(keep="?")*(lastaccess<=last_date),
calc,TOROW(UNIQUE(FILTER(return,conditional))),
conc,CONCAT(calc&delimiter),
result,IFERROR(LEFT(conc,LEN(conc)-LEN(delimiter)),if_not_found),
result)
```

Comment: I hadn't made it a structured table yet as I was just working with a temporary dataset to get things working, but I didn't know about CHOOSEROWS and CHOOSECOLS, so this is actually really useful to know, cheers! A nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, it sounds like you're using the same formula in 17 different locations throughout the workbook. As such, I would highly recommend that you define all of your variables (usernames, names, emails, boards, access, keep and lastaccess) as *Named Ranges* in **Name Manager**, and eliminate the LET function altogether.

The scope of the variables defined within the LET function cannot extend beyond the function itself, whereas **Name Manager** can define variables to be used on a specific worksheet or throughout the entire workbook.

On the ribbon, go to the **Formulas Tab > Defined Names Group > Name Manager** and define a new name for each of the above-mentioned variables. It should look like this when you are done:

[image: name_manager.jpg]

Next, use input cells in your worksheet for *Column*, *Board* and *Date* (ie: L30, L31 and L32). Create a drop-down list in cell `L30` to choose the desired column name to be returned... on the ribbon, go to the **Data Tab > Data Tools Group > Data Validation**, select *List* and use the three defined names that you want to choose from as the **Source:** *usernames,names,emails*.

[image: data_validation.jpg]

The formula you can now use throughout your workbook to filter and return the desired comma-separated list would be:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(INDIRECT(L30),
   (boards=L31)*(access="")*(lastaccess<=L32)*(keep = "?"),"None"))
```

You may also want to consider creating a LAMBDA function, since it will be used in 17 different locations. To do this, open **Name Manager** again and define a new name called *GET.LIST*, using the following function as the **Refers to:**

```
=LAMBDA(column_name, board, access_date,
TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(INDIRECT(column_name),
   (boards=board)*(access="")*(lastaccess<=access_date)*(keep = "?"),"None"))
)
```

Once created, the final simplified formula you can use throughout your workbook would be:

```
=GET.LIST(L30,L31,L32)
```

With this method, if you ever needed to modify the conditions specified in the *include* parameter of the FILTER function, you would only need to modify it ONCE in **Name Manager**. Cheers!

Comment: This is a good solution and I did know I could use named ranges to accomplish something similar, it was more a point of interest as I was working with the LET function if something like that was available. Reason being that LET was added to try emulate variables like programming languages have, so being able to cross reference variables could be a nice thing!